# WPF Application = Exe + DLL + Custom Visualizer ? Can I do all 3 of them?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, .net-framework-version, visualizer

As the title says, I have a WPF form that I want to build in 3 separate projects:

1. A Windows application, used standalone by clicking the .exe file
2. A GUI control that can be imported and used in some other projects (dll)
3. A Custom Visualizer, that can also be used to view a collection of some specific types (dll)

The interface and all the functionality will be the same(identical) between the 3 projects

My questions are the following:

- Can this be achieved by making only one project? Or do I have to make 3 separate projects?
- If there is not other way but to make 3 separate projects, how can I have the logic for the controls in a separate project common for all of them?
  All the logic is now in the controls events (MouseWheel, button click etc)
- I need to use net framework 4.7.2 (or 4.8). Can I make all the projects with this? Or can I also use .net 6.0 on some of them?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In such case, you can use a `Shared Project`. Add a `Shared Project` (case-sensitive) to your solution and reference that project from other pojects. Then you can access the code inside the `Shared Project` from other projects as if the code belongs to each of other projects.

`Shared Project` is often explained in the context of sharing the codes among different platforms but it could be useful for other purpose as well.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to implement this and I will come back with an update (sorry to respond so late, but I didn't have access to my computer until now)